# Get <li> element on click - vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a function that every time the user inserts a value in an input it adds a `<li>` element inside a `<ul>`.
that same function creates the `<li>` with the attribute ( `onclick="doneToggle"` ).

```
function createListElement() {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    ul.appendChild(li);
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
    li.setAttribute("onclick", "doneToggle()")
    li.setAttribute("style", "width: fit-content")
    input.value = "";
}
```

doneToggle is a function that I want to add a specific class to that element, that css class makes the text have a "line-through" style.

so far this is the function

```
function doneToggle(element) {
    element.classList.toggle("done");
}
```

I want that function to retrieve that clicked element and toggle its class without having to assign IDs to the `<li>`'s.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Element.prototype.addEventListener()` instead of `onclick`. This way the `event` is automatically passed to the handler function, which allows to access the `event.target` element that the event was raised on.

Instead of

```
li.setAttribute("onclick", "doneToggle()")
```

do

```
li.addEventListener('click', doneToggle)
```

Then work with the `event` passed using `event.target` which contains the clicked element:

```
function doneToggle(event) {
    event.target.classList.toggle("done");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In an event listener function, `this` refers to the element that triggered the event, so instead of using `element`, which is actually and Event Object, use `this`:

```
function doneToggle(event) {
    this.classList.toggle("done");
}
```

And instead of changing the "onclick" attribute, add an event Listener:

```
function createListElement() {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    ul.appendChild(li);
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
    li.addEventListener("click", doneToggle)
    li.setAttribute("style", "width: fit-content")
    input.value = "";
}
```

Comment: When using `onclick="doneToggle()"` there will be no `event` passed to it.